# where to check CU version for workflow manager 1.0 in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager-farm

We have SharePoint onpremises farm with Workflow manager 1.0 installed in 3 SharePoint servers.

We need to update the CU version for Workflow manager and service bus.

Where to check the current installed CU version for workflow manger 1.0 in windows server 2008 R2?

Is there any powershell to find the version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another old fashioned way to check it.

- Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features
- You will see the Service bus and Worklfow Manager witht heir curernt build version number.
- If you click on the Installed Updates > then you will see all the Installed updates / KB for Workflow manager and Service bus.
  [image]

Answer (score 4):

To see which version of Workflow Manager and Service Bus are installed, use the following PowerShell:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts\Microsoft.Workflow.Service.dll").VersionInfo
(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.0\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll").VersionInfo
```

or

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.1\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll").VersionInfo
```

Reference: [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346). This post also includes a list of available versions and download-links.